# Update query works, but listbox not showing the update/change

Tags: c#, sql, listbox

I made a windows form where you can search a movie with its name. Then you can update the record.
But when I try to do this I get the messagebox that the update has been saved but when I reload the listbox I see no changes.

The Update method.

```
public void Update()
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();


        string commandostring = "UPDATE Movies SET " +
                " name = '" + this.name+ "'," +

                " releaseDate = #" + this.releaseDate + "#, " +
                " lenghtInMinutes = " + this.lenghtInMinutes +
                " WHERE movieId = " + this.movieId;


        command.CommandText = commandostring;
        command.Connection = conn;
        adapter.UpdateCommand = command;


        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        conn.Close();
    }
```

Windows Form update:

```
  private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            private Movie Movie1;
            Movie1.Name= textBoxName.Text;
            Movie1.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxReleaseDate.Text);
            Movie1.LenghtInMinutes= Convert.ToInt32(textBoxLenghtInMinutes.Text);

            Movie1.Update();
            MessageBox.Show("Changes saved");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Filling the listbox

```
private void fillListBox()
    {

        List<Movie> movies = Movie.AllMovies();
        listBox1.DataSource = movies;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "AllData";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "MovieId";


    }
```

All Movies method

```
public static List<Movie> AllMovies()
    {


        string command;
        command = "SELECT movieId, name, headActor, director, actorId, directorId, releaseDate, lenghtInMinutes "
            + "FROM Movies order by movieId";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(datatable);


        List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>();
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.movieId = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int>("movieId");
            movie.name = datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("name");
            movie.headActor = datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("headActor");
            movie.director = datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("director");
            movie.actorId = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int?>("actorId");
            movie.directorId = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int?>("directorId");
            movie.releaseDate = datatable.Rows[i].Field<DateTime>("releaseDate");
            movie.lenghtInMinutes = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int>("lenghtInMinutes");
            list.Add(movie);






        }
        return lijst;
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by reloading the listbox ... do you mean re-binding it?

Comment: It looks like you lost reference to Movie1, don't you? You update it on DB side, but you don't reference it on application side anywhare. After finish this part of code, the Movi1 is destroyed, because of lack of references.

Answer (score 0):

To update the database I would use a parameterized query

```
public void Update()
{
    string commandostring = "UPDATE Movies SET " +
                            "name = ?,releaseDate = ?,lenghtInMinutes = ? " +
                            "WHERE movieId = ?";
    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandostring, conn))
    {
         conn.Open();
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",this.name);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",this.releaseDate);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",this.lenghtInMinutes);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",this.movieId);
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Then, regarding the listbox updating, looking at your previous question, it seems that the listbox is filled assigning a `List<Movie>` to its datasource. To update the listbox you should find the item that you want to change (usually it is the SelectedItem) then manually change the Movie instance stored in the SelectedItem and use it to update the database

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Here we need to get the current movie from the current item 
        // selected in the listbox and update this instance
        if(listBoxForMovies.SelectedItem != null) 
        {
             Movie currentMovie = listBoxForMovies.SelectedItem as Movie;
             currentMovie.Name= textBoxName.Text;
             currentMovie.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxReleaseDate.Text);
             currentMovie.LenghtInMinutes= Convert.ToInt32(textBoxLenghtInMinutes.Text);
             currentMovie.Update();
             MessageBox.Show("Changes saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

To resolve the usual problem of communication between two forms you could apply this simple tecnique.

In FormSearchMovies

```
public class FormSearchMovies:Form
{
    private ListBox listBoxForMovies = null;

    public void FormSearchMovice(ListBox listFromParentForm)
    {
        listBoxForMovies = listFromParentForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In FormListMovies

```
using(FormSearchMovies frmSearch = new FormSearchMovies(listbox1))
{
     frmSearch.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I edited it with extra code.
When I want to make that last change you suggest i get an error that there are is no return type.

Comment: In the update code is missing the MovieID, I mean the call to the Update method for the Movie class requires a correct value for the movieid, but this value is not assigned to the variable. This leads to a failing update

Comment: Answer updated. could you tell me where you get the error message

Comment: This worked, but only if I would do that in the same form as the listbox.

I have  a form FormSearchMovie where you can search a movie on its name and then update it. the listbox is in the FormListMovies. How do i make a reference to that listbox so i can use it in another form

Comment: The classic way to solve this issue is to pass the reference of the listbox from FormListMovies to FormSearchMovies when you create the second one. Keep this reference in a global variable inside the FormSearchMovies and update that reference. Added an example